# Computer randomly powering off (not restarting)

Tags: cpu, hardware-failure, overheating

Over the past few weeks I've started to see my Windows-based machine randomly powering off. Mem-test returns nothing and I'm tossing between it being a memory problem or a processor problem.

I'm more convinced that it's the processor overheating. Computer hardware isn't my strong point but is there any way I can definitively prove it's the processor before seeking out to purchase a new one?

Here's an XML dump from the event viewer (if it's helpful or not is beyond me).

I've also attached what Speedfan is showing me. Are these high temperature readings for a CPU?

[image]

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" /> 
  <EventID>41</EventID> 
  <Version>2</Version> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <Task>63</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000002</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-11-05T21:54:52.112832700Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>46655</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>User-PC</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="SleepInProgress">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: Run a CPU stress test. Wait for shutdown, and wait for system to cool down.Remove side of case. Point desk or box fan at CPU. Stress test again.

Comment: Great idea! I'll give it a go :) I've noticed there's no external fans on the case which I didn't realise until today so heat may be the issue.

Comment: That dosen't sound right 0_0

Comment: Good old local computer shops who claim they can build good machines cheap!

Comment: I have had this issue with a previous PC. The first thing that comes to mind is overheating CPU (Or maybe even the GPU or PSU). In the BIOS menu of your computer you can set your PC to shutdown at a certain temperature. Sometimes you can set these fail-safe temperatures a little higher. Sometimes you just need to clean the PC so it can cool properly. Another likely possibility is a faulty PSU. A fault PSU is very hard to diagnose. It leaves no logs, or other detectable trace of any fault if it fails at random intervals. The best way to test for this is by replacing the PSU (temporarily).

Comment: The stress test didn't even power my machine off. Memtest returned no faults in the memory but I've now installed a fan and I'm seeing much lower temperature readings. Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is **overheating CPU** (Or maybe even the GPU or PSU). In the **BIOS menu** of your computer you can set your PC to shutdown at a certain temperature. Sometimes you can set these **fail-safe temperatures** a little higher. Sometimes you just need to **clean the PC** so it can cool properly.

Another likely possibility is a **faulty PSU**. A faulty PSU is very hard to diagnose. It leaves no logs, or other detectable trace of any fault if it fails at random intervals. The best way to test for this is by **replacing the PSU (temporarily)**.

If you need more information on any of these possibilities, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I downloaded and installed HeavyLoad last night and performed a stress test against the CPU and GPU. I left it running for around 5 minutes but it didn't power off. I've not yet checked out the BIOS - but I can see I'm running an `AMD FX(tm)-4130 at 3.80GHz` - I'm wondering if the computer shop that my Dad purchased the computer from may have overclocked it? I'll check it out and dig a little deeper!

Comment: @Laim McArthur If your stress-test was good, but the CPU did not overheat, that is a hint it might not be an overheating issue. A faulty PSU is still quite possible, but there is no way to test for that other than trying to run the PC with another PSU for a while to see if the problem is resolved that way. If you have some other PC you don't need for a while with a compatible PSU, you might want to take it out and put in in your trouble machine. It's a lot of work and not much certainty, but it's the only way to check for a faulty PSU, without needing specialist tools.

Comment: And by all means, keep pursuing your own intuition! You might discover something none of us came up with. If you do, please also post that solution for future reference.

Comment: I've installed a fan to the case and temperature readings (at the moment) are reading much lower. Memtest returned no errors so I'll continued to monitor!

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like this is an issue with your computer's power button apparatus. I may be wrong, but this happened to me before and my event dump looked very similar to that. I never got around to fix it, but my power button had been smashed by a screwdriver, and broke; anyways, I would open your system and look to see if there are any exposed wires or if your power button looks strange. You also didn't specify if your computer instantly turns off, or your computer goes into shutdown mode. If it goes into shutdown mode, My solution may work. If not, it is probably an issue with your PSU or CPU.

Comment: I'll open her up tomorrow and take a look. I haven't even looked at the wires for the power button yet - it never really crossed my mind but I'll certainly look!

The computer is completely powering off. It doesn't enter the Windows shutdown process - just straight into darkness!

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

This could be a power supply issue.  Those are notoriously difficult to troubleshoot.  But this definitely feels like a power issue to me.

If you had a RAM problem, you would get a BSOD, not a hard shutdown.  If it were a CPU issue, it'd lock up on you.

Those temps are a bit high, but not wildly so.  Also, both the GPU and the CPU have a throttle on them, so if they were overheating they'd just slow down to a crawl but they wouldn't kill power to the system.

On some computers, the BIOS will kill power to the system if the computer is overheating, but firmware logic like that would also have a log to tell you that's what happened.  Check to see if your BIOS has that feature.